# Postgres - How to use psql to create a database with the -c command and password authentication?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, command-line, passwords, psql

If I run the following:

```
psql -h localhost -U admin -c "CREATE DATABASE sales OWNER admin;"
```

It returns:

> psql FATAL:  database "admin" does not exist

I need to use password authentication and have setup .pgpass as follows:

```
localhost:*:*:admin:admin
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when you connect as a user, the database connected to is the DB of the same name as the user.

If you want to connect to a different DB, you must specify it in the `psql` command line. Since in this case you're trying to create the DB, you can't connect to it yet, you must connect to another DB (like `template1` or `postgres`) that already exists.

E.g.

```
psql -h localhost -U admin template1 -c "CREATE DATABASE sales OWNER admin;"
                           ^^^^^^^^^
```